# retrieve single object from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Is it possible to just retrieve a single object of an .json file? What i have is:

**data.json**

```
{
  "0": {
    "test": "0"
  },
  "1": {
    "test": "1"
  }
}
```

**script.js**

```
  var data = "";
  var Id = '1';

  $.getJSON(linktofile, function(data) {
    data = data;
    if (data[Id] == null) {
      x = "<h4>Any Text</h4>";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    } else {
      if (data[ID].test != 0) {
        x += "<span>" + data[ID].test + "</span>";
      }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
  });
```

At the moment I get the complete data from the .json file. My problem is that the .json file is over 5000 lines long and sometimes it took 1 second or 2 to finish the complete function.
Is there any thing like:

**script.js**

```
$.getJSON(linktofile, function(data[Id]) {
  //do anything with the data
});
```

So I only retrieve the part I need and not the complete data?

Comment: You would need to handle that on the server side. I.e. your API needs to support retrieving items by their ID.

Comment: if (data[ID].test != 0) {    should be   if (data[Id].test != 0) {

Comment: the linktofile file needs to accept a post parameter that indicates what data to return, use $.ajax or $.post to send parameters

Answer (score 1):

JSON [demo data](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) file from [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

```js
(function() {

$.getJSON( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", function( json ) {
  
 // Specify the index to retrieve
 var index = 1;
  
 // Get specific index data
 var data = json[index];

 // Get the name for example
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.name;

});

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```